# Is it abuse to answer then dupe-hammer a question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, abuse

I recently came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880832/how-to-return-a-promise-when-writestream-finishes) in the Reopen Queue. A gold badge holder answered the question (which went on to be accepted and gain a lot of upvotes), then exactly one minute later dupe-hammered it and closed it, preventing it from receiving any more answers.

Is this considered abusing the dupe-hammer? I can't think of any good reasons why this would be acceptable, because if one votes to close a question and prevent any answers, then it is total hypocrisy to answer the question yourself. Am I missing something important, or is this a case of abusing the dupe-hammer?

Comment: I belive it is though dont quote me on it

Comment: It is site-legal and in absolutely no way site-abusive, but having said that, I will add that I'm not sure that it passes my own personal smell test. But I'll also add that my smell test doesn't count for much, either here or at home.

Comment: People change their minds sometimes; or they find canonical duplicates after attempting an answer (sometimes, finding a duplicate is much harder than it ought to be, even for very commonly asked questions. Typically, **because** it's so commonly asked.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks, I hadn't considered that before. However, in the answer I mentioned in my question the gold badge holder dupe-hammered exactly 1 minute after answering, which seems a bit fast to change one's mind.

Comment: Sounds like a "gray area" case to me. The dupe target is really "canonical", about the general case. The particular case may still need a particular answer. The number of votes this answer won accross the years kind of confirms that it was indeed useful. But the target still does answer that question, more indirectly maybe, but with more useful details about the general case. Closing as a dupe seems like a correct action too. Should they have written a CommunityWiki instead? Probably, but I wouldn't blame them for not doing so.

Comment: From experience, it happened to me a couple of times. After I answer someone suggests a perfect dupe I couldn't find, so I closed with it. My answers add nothing new (even though "tailored" to askers) so I deleted them to not fragment the information. I consider  doing otherwise with a dupe hammer to be disingenuous.

Comment: I feel ambivalent about these. I agree it smells a bit, but I wouldn't consider it abuse. Two hearts beat in my chest: the question should be closed as the hundredth duplicate of that canonical question, and it shouldn't receive any new answers. At the same time, to really help the OP, they usually need an answer tailored to their code. Usually I provide that in a comment after closing the question, but code blocks in comments are awful … (1/2)

Comment: … and in this particular case the question already had received a harmful answer (forgetting error handling) so I guess I decided to post an answer with formatted code for better visibility. I did not expect to the answer to be accepted (which indeed didn't happen for 3 weeks) or gain a lot of upvotes, I'm actually surprised it did get +35 over 7 years. I admit I don't feel too bad about that - but if you all prefer to have a community wiki answer (or think that something is missing from the answer and it could need an edit), I would convert it. (2/2)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel In this particular case, I'm certain that I knew the canonical question when posting the answer - it's the second-most common dupe target for [[tag:promise]]-questions. (Finding the proper canonical after answering also happens to me, but not here). It might have been a case of change-of-minds, where I first thought about only linking the canonical from the answer, and then later decided to just close it, I don't remember.

Comment: Is it "abuse" to provide personalised help to someone even though you "shouldn't" answer a question that should be closed? Yeah I guess it is. I don't want to go to a place where we actively punish it though. It is the kind of abuse I would be very happy with to just look the other way... except when there is proof of frequent repetition for personal gain.

Comment: I do agree with Bergi here that answer + dupe closure is the much better alternative. Dupe closure would leave an incorrect answer in place which users could use and that's not what we want. Just answering leaves a fracture in the knowledge base. The *only* other alternatives are: 1. removing the answer and dupe closure 2. adding a correct answer and dupe closure. Where 1. is quite hard to achieve thus leaving 2. as the most viable option.

Comment: Yes, it's abuse. *By definition*, closure means that the question can't (or shouldn't) be answered (unless they think that only they should be allowed to answer). It's never appropriate to both answer and vote to close.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine "*(unless they think that only they should be allowed to answer)*" there *is* another answer already. And it's wrong. And it's upvoted multiple times. But the question is a duplicate. So, do you say it's *more* appropriate to leave the wrong and misleading answer active and prevent any more answers? We have evidence users have already been mislead by it due to the multiple upvotes. Or do you say we should avoid consolidating the knowledge here and post a correct answer instead? Which course of action do you advocate for here?

Comment: @VLAZ If the gold badge holder felt that the question should receive more answers after all, they shouldn't have closed it. Closing something that ought to receive more answers is directly contrary to the purpose of close voting.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine in that case, you're suggesting that we should ***not*** be trying to consolidate related knowledge together, is that correct? Having a wrong answer trumps pooling content together?

Comment: In this case, it seems like the question should be marked as a dupe, but not closed. If only a gold badge holder is allowed to answer, then it would be undemocratic to disallow someone else to correct the gold badge holder (if need be). Currently there's no way to do this, but maybe there should be.

Comment: "*disallow someone else to correct the gold badge holder (if need be)*" - there's always reopen votes, so I don't feel bad to close a question - directing visitors to the canonical question is my motivation, not preventing "competing" answers. I'm happy to have my answers corrected, if need be, and if someone wants to write better answer I'm ready to hammer the question open again.